# Scrapy ignoring content after # tag in the URL

Tags: python, url, scrapy

Hi i am scraping a site which has the URl like below

```
http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx#RSS=pgZZ1QQdivZZctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03
```

i had placed this in `start_url` and requested a response , but i received the response as below

```
<200 http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx>
```

That is, it simply ignores the content after `hash tag`, so i had read some post and came to know that, when we request a url with hash tag the server simply ignores the hash fragments, i mean hash fragments are used to load some extra information for ajax or javascript requests.so i had replaced the url in `start_url` with an `exclamatory mark(!)` after `# tag` as below

```
http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx#!RSS=pgZZ1QQdivZZctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03
```

And now the output is

```
<GET http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx?_escaped_fragment_=RSS=pgZZ1QQdivZZctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03
```

I had done this by reading this post `https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started`,  According to the concept in this post i need to convert the output URL with `?_escaped_fragment_=` to the URL containing `#` (I mean the original URL)to parse the page completely without scrapy ignoring the hash fragment.How to convert it.

I hope i explained well, if not please correct me and let me know the concept of how to make scrapy of not ignoring the hash fragments from a URL.

Thanks in advance...............

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrapy, hash tag on URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604690/scrapy-hash-tag-on-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter. With or without the hash the URI refers to exactly the same page.

The stuff after the hash is a fragment identifier. Your browser will use it to scroll the page to that specific part of the page.

Like this...

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#h-2.1.2

...and this...

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html

..both retrieve the same page. The former simply tells you where on the page to start reading.

EDIT:

start_urls = ['themobilestore.in/home-mobiles-&-tablet/?page=1', 'themobilestore.in/home-mobiles-&-tablet/?page=2', ]

Comment: Thanks for u reply, but the result is not same when we use the url without hash fragments right? For example in the above url with hash fragments if suppose RSS=1 and 2 and so on... i mean if it is used for acheiving pagination like http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx#RSS=1,http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx#RSS=2,http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx#RSS=3..... In this stage we need the data of url with hash fragment so how to achieve this

Comment: They _should_ retrieve the same page. The behaviour you are describing is appropriate for a question mark '?', not a hash '#'.  Perhaps the site in question is doing something non-standard.  What is the URL?

Comment: sorry if i am wrong, we got question mark '? after including exclamatory mark ! after # in the URL http://www.example.com/categories-Mobile-Phones.aspx#RSS=pgZZ1QQdivZZctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03 the actual URL is this one which i intend to parse teh page

Comment: For example take this site http://www.themobilestore.in/home-mobiles-&-tablet#/?page=1 Here we can achieve pagination by changing the integer at the end for the page, but when we give this to start_url we can get response by ignoring #fragments, so how to acheive this

Comment: The hash is redundant there. You're actually calling two different pages. One with the parameter page=1 and another with page=2.  This is basic http/html and nothing to do with scrapy. You need to feed it both start urls, or hope that the link is on the page somewhere the spider will find it and call naturally.  You could build functionality in the spider to pagination but that is something for later. Please accept the answer if it has been helpful.

Comment: Sure it is very helpfull, actually there is no href(link) to achieve pagination in HTML and i think replacing # with ? doen't work every time, and this is my intension to ask whether we can make by an other alternative of accessing with hash fragments, Any way thanks for u r support

Comment: ?! There are certainly <a href> links to the other pages on the page you cite. And they don't have any #'s in them, so I don't understand what your deal is but you've totally sapped my patience now. Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry i doesn't mean that i had given that site as an example for u , because u asked for the url, its really very helpfull, yes as u said this site has url(hrefs) but what if there is no url and need to achieve pagination, please don't consider that url as of now this is my intension and not more than that, anyway sorry and thanks for u r support.