# How to avoid scrapy ignoring hash tag

Tags: python, url, scrapy

i am working on scrapy

I had a site to scrape with hash tag included , but when i run it , scrapy downloading the response by ignoring hash tag

For example this is the url with `hash fragments`, `url="www.example.com/hash-tag.php#user_id-654"`
and the response from this request is only `www.example.com/hash-tag.php`, but i want to scrape the url with hash fragments.

My code is below

```
 class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
     name = "example"
     domain_name = "www.example.com"


    def start_requests(self):
            return Request("www.example.com/hash-tag.php#user_id-654")    


    def parse(self):
           print response
```

Result:

```
<GET www.example.com/hash-tag.php>
```

How can i do this...... 
Thanks in advance................

Comment: How does the hash tag add extra information? hash-tags are never sent to a server, they are browser-side-only information, and any extra info in a page is then either already there or loaded with JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Thanks for your reply i realized that they are browser-side-only information , i will edit my question if necessary,but is there a way in scrapy to avoid ignoring hash tag because i want to achieve pagination  in one of the site, so when i clicked on page numbers a url with above format(i mean including hash tag) is generated. so i want to use that hash tag and dynamically pass values to achieve pagination, this is my intension, can u provide me a way, i hope u understand this..

Comment: What you see in the location bar is not quite the same as what is sent to the server.  Use a browser with detailed network reporting tools (in chrome, press CTRL-SHIFT-I, click on Network, use the target site) so that you can see what is being sent back and forth.  Chances are good that you will see that the actual request urls are very different from the url in the location bar; the page is being constructed dynamically by javascript, but from regular resources fetched behind the scenes

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Thanks for u r reply i had already tried posting the form by the values seeing in chrome network tool,i got an exact issue here can u please have a look at it "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078916/scrapy-ignoring-content-after-tag-in-the-url"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrapy, hash tag on URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604690/scrapy-hash-tag-on-urls)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not easily possible. To achieve what you want you need a full DOM and JavaScript engine, i.e. a (possibly headless) browser.

If you really need it, have a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It is the WebKit engine but completely headless. I'm not sure if scrapy can be easily extended but if you really want to execute JavaScript (which you need in this case), using PhantomJS is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I edited my code above, can u give me an example on how do it on above

Comment: It is far away from being trivial and actually writing the code for that way outside the scope of an answer here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really need that information you could just do split string before calling Request, and send that information as meta.

Something like

```
url = "www.example.com/hash-tag.php#user_id-654"
hash = url.split("#")[1]

request = Request(url, callback=self.parse_something)
request.meta['after_hash'] = hash
yield request
```

and then in parsing get and use it like

```
def parse_something(self, response):
     hash = response.meta['after_hash']
```

That is if you only need that information after hash sign.

Comment: I mean i am trying to achieve pagination in a site with url "www.example.com/hash-tag.php#user_id-1 for page 1 and "www.example.com/hash-tag.php#user_id-2" for page 2 so on, so i had given this url in start_request method for trying, but it is ignoring hash fragments,here i can achieve pagination eigther if request is made with url including hash fragments or posting the form with values by viewing in chrome, but i want whether we can make scrapy execute url with hash tag or any alternative to achieve this........ sorry if am anything wrong.... thanksin advance

Comment: and why can't you just get all the data and do pagination yourself, wouldn't that be better way. if you want pagination you need to implement it yourself