# Requesting URLs with base64 data encoded

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, base64

I'm trying to request a URL with data encoded in base64 on it, like so:

`http://www.somepage.com/es_e/bla_bla#eyJkYXRhIjp7ImNvdW50cnlJZCI6IkVTIiwicmVnaW9uSWQiOiI5MjAiLCJkdXJhdGlvbiI6NywibWluUGVyc29ucyI6MX0sImNvbmZpZyI6eyJwYWdlIjoiMCJ9fQ==`

What I do, is build a JSON object, encode it into base64, and append it to a url like this:

```
new_data = {"data": {"countryId": "ES", "regionId": "920", "duration": 7, "minPersons": 1}, "config": {"page": 2}}
json_data = json.dumps(new_data)
new_url = "http://www.somepage.com/es_es/bla_bla#" + base64.b64encode(json_data)
yield scrapy.Request(url=new_url, callback=self.parse)
```

The problem is that Scrapy crawls only this part of the URL `http://www.somepage.com/es_es/bla_bla` without the data encoded and appended to it...however, if I paste the `new_url` into the browser, it shows me the result I want with the data encoded!

Don't know what's happening...Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: The query fragment (part of the URL after `#`), only applies to browsers. Servers ignore that part of a URL.

Comment: Javascript code loaded by the browser is free to use the query fragment to alter behaviour. E.g. a script may use that part to load AJAX data or alter the page in some way. That's all client-side, and has nothing to do with what the server sends the browser.

Comment: so, there's no way to achieve the same on the server side?! @MartijnPieters

Comment: You'd have to simulate a full browser, if there is JS code to be executed. Selenium is the go-to option for that.

Comment: I've been reading a while about Selenium, but I'm a bit confused about how to use it to solve my problem...do you know how to do it?! @MartijnPieters

Comment: Sorry, I've not used Selenium in years now.

Comment: ok, no problem, thank you so much anyway for the info you gave me. At least I know a bit more about my problem! @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After been searching a lot, I read that this kind of URLs, the one with a `#` at the end (i.e. my URL `http://www.somepage.com/es_e/bla_bla#eyJkYXRhIjp7ImNvdW50cnlJZCI6IkVTIiwicmVnaW9uSWQiOiI5MjAiLCJkdXJhdGlvbiI6NywibWluUGVyc29ucyI6MX0sImNvbmZpZyI6eyJwYWdlIjoiMCJ9fQ==`) are called ***Fragment URLs*** and basically they indicate a location within a resource, like an anchor (you can read it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html)).

And then, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604690/scrapy-hash-tag-on-urls) I learned that those contents need to be loaded by the page, so the website itself makes requests to get that data (Outgoing Requests), so what I did was to search for those ***Outgoing Requests*** using Firefox Developer Edition (you can use any other system that shows you these requests, like Tamper Data), and build the URL that gives me the HTML content I was looking for.

```
# The base64 data encoded as a JSON is appended after the 'searchRequest=' instead of using the '#' element, and voilà!
"http://www.somewebsite.es/?controller=ajaxresults&action=getresults&searchRequest=eyJkYXRhIjp7ImNvdW50cnlJZCI6IkVTIiwicmVnaW9uSWQiOiI5MjAiLCJkdXJhdGlvbiI6N30sImNvbmZpZyI6eyJwYWdlIjoiMCJ9fQ=="
```

I could also achieve this by using the **Selium** library, as you can see in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604275/how-to-yield-fragment-urls-in-scrapy-using-selenium), but isn't the best practice...