# Scrapy Spider - For loop within response callback not iterating

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use the link parsing structure described by "warwaruk" in this SO thread:
[Following links, Scrapy web crawler framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591255/following-links-scrapy-web-crawler-framework)

This works great when only grabbing a single item from each page. However, when I try to create a for loop to scrape all items within each page, it appears that the parse_item function terminates upon reaching the first yield statement. I have a custom pipeline setup to handle each item, but currently it only receives one item per page.

Let me know if I need to include more code, or clarification. THANKS!

```
def parse_item(self,response):  
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    prices = hxs.select("//div[contains(@class, 'item')]/script/text()").extract()
    for prices in prices:
        item = WalmartSampleItem()
        ...
        yield items
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `yield` a single `item` in the for loop, not `items`:

```
for prices in prices:
    item = WalmartSampleItem()
    ...
    yield item
```

Comment: It still seems to have the same issue, I just accidentally added that the s when I pasted the code in.